# Converting Array inside a String into a list of items with PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I'm receiving from an API a JavaScript array inside a string like the following:

```
'["qwe","asd","zxc","345"]'
```

And I'm trying to get it to become a list of items, which I did.

```
SELECT  regexp_substr(
          REPLACE( 
            REPLACE(
              REPLACE('["qwe","asd","zxc","345"]', '"', ''),
            '[',''),
          ']',''),
        '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS Lista
FROM  dual
CONNECT BY instr(REPLACE( 
            REPLACE(
              REPLACE('["qwe","asd","zxc","345"]', '"', ''),
            '[',''),
          ']','')
          , ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0;
```

The problems is that it doesn't feel right.

Please, can someone help me to either optimize/improve the code or maybe confirm that this is it and there is nothing to be done.

Thx

Comment: With supported (modern) Oracle Versions you can use `json_table()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on 12.1.0.2 or higher, the "correct" way to do this is with `json_table`

```
select * from json_table (
  '["qwe","asd","zxc","345"]', '$[*]'
  columns (
    val path '$'
  )
);

VAL   
qwe    
asd    
zxc    
345
```

Comment: Yes, awesome Chris, I knew there was a better way. Thx